# the page 1 was request but the document has only 0 pages

Tags: java, android, document, runtimeexception

So I am trying to generate a report that may contain many pages depending upon the user input and data.

Similar error was summarized [here](http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/RuntimeExcpetion-Size-of-pageReferences-and-currentPageNumber-1-Are-Not-Equal-td3445663.html) but its not seen to be the actual solution of the problem.

**My function:**

```
public void generateReport()
{
  final String path = "/sdcard/testreport.pdf";
  try
  {
  Document document = new Document();
  writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(FILE));
  document.open();
  // many lines code related to report generation
  writer.setOpenAction(action);
  status = GetReport(document);
  document.close(); //RunTimeException here.
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

But I am getting RunTimeException as-

**Log**

```
04-16 19:34:01.928: W/System.err(14248): java.lang.RuntimeException: The page 1 was requested but the document has only 0 pages.
04-16 19:34:01.929: W/System.err(14248):    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.close(PdfWriter.java:1208)
04-16 19:34:01.929: W/System.err(14248):    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.close(PdfDocument.java:776)
04-16 19:34:01.929: W/System.err(14248):    at com.itextpdf.text.Document.close(Document.java:420)
04-16 19:34:01.929: W/System.err(14248):    at com.wassap.main.ReportsActivity.generateReport(ReportsActivity.java:541)
```

I am not getting the clue as of how to close the document only if to know in advance if the page is there.

Comment: Why are you using a PDF writer to open a file that you apparently want to read?  Should you be using PdfReader() instead?

Comment: It isn't just to read but also to write. Also, the function contains many lines of code but I only mentioned the relevant lines that are causing the actual problem as mentioned in the question comment itself in the code.

Comment: No as for PdfReader(). You imagine as I am opening the report, writing into it and then closing the report. Then getting exception on close().

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, but an answer may help others coming across it later.

I had this same error. In my case, the PDF I was creating only had 1 page, but the PdfAction I created was calling `PdfAction.GotoLocalPage(2, pdfDest, writer)`. Since there was no page 2, the "page requested" error was thrown.

If your error is that there are 0 pages, I wonder if you are experiencing some error that is causing your PDF code to not run and therefore not create any pages in the generated PDF.

One other thought is that I don't see a `document.NewPage()` call in the sample code you included. Maybe there are multiple ways to create new pages, but that's the call I make to manually add new pages. If you don't have any of those calls, maybe that's why there are no pages in the PDF?